# Spring data, derived repository method

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a working mongo repository

```
@Repository
interface NewsRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<News, String> {

    fun findByUserId(userId: String): Flux<News>

    fun findByType(type: NewsType, pageable: Pageable): Flux<News>

    fun countByType(type: NewsType): Long
}
```

The services can call this repository's `findByUserId` and `findByType` methods and return a list of news.

As soon as I call `countByType` I get the following exception:

```
System.out.println(newsRepository.countByType(NewsType.OFFICIAL))
```

> 19-10-28 14:44:25.131 DEBUG 2986 --- [ctor-http-nio-4]
>   o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator        : Created query Query: {
>   "type" : { "$java" : OFFICIAL } }, Fields: { }, Sort: { } 2019-10-28
>   14:44:25.165 ERROR 2986 --- [ctor-http-nio-4]
>   a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [a29dfc95] 500 Server Error
>   for HTTP GET "/api/user/news/pages"
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Long  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.countByType(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]

I'm guessing this has to do with the ReactiveMongoRepository signature `<News, String>`

`countByxxx` seems to be a thing (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/derived-count-query.html) and since `findByType` works I'm confused...

Comment: Since this is a reactive repository, try changing your `Long` return type to a `Mono<Long>`.

Comment: I tried but it just prints "MonoOnErrorResume"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in a ReactiveMongoRepository I cannot have a method that returns a "non reactive" data type.

So in addition to the original `NewsRepository` I created a `NewsAggregationRepository` that looks like

```
@Repository
interface NewsAggregationRepository: CrudRepository<News, Long> {

    fun countByType(type: NewsType): Long
}
```

This time it extends CrudRepository

I can inject this repository in my services along the reactive one:

```
class NewsServiceImpl(private val newsRepository: NewsRepository, private val newsAggregationRepository: NewsAggregationRepository)
```

And call reactive and non reactive methods from there

```
sysout(newsAggregationRepository.countByType(xxx))
sysout(newsRepository.getNews())
```